# Bootstrap Form jQuery $.post without refreshing page and PHP send mail

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have define all parameter in my code but not able to resolve error is Notice: Undefined index: fname in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\process.php on line 3. i have define but steel getting this error. when removing first field from the form rest is working fine.
Below is my bootstrap index.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script>
 
$(document).ready(function(){
 
$("#submit").click(function(){   
 
 
    var  postname = $("#fname").val();
       
    var postemail = $("#email").val();
       
    var postphone = $("#phone").val();
       
       
       
      $.post("process.php", {fname:postname, email:postemail, phone:postphone }, function(postresult) {
       
      $("#postdiv").html(postresult);
 
    });


}); 
 
 
});

 
</script>
 <style type="text/css">
  .box {
   width: 900px; 
   background: gray;
   color: white;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 10px;
   text-align: center;
  }
  #postdiv{
    margin-left: 50px;
    width:30%;
    background-color:#eee;
}  
 </style>

    </head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<h1>Bootstrap Form jQuery $.post without refreshing page  </h1>
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for=""  class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter Name">
        </div>
      </div>
        
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for=""  class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email">
        </div>
      </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone">
        </div>
      </div>           

    </form>
   </div> 
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-5">   
<button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-warning">Submit</button>
</div><br /><br /><br />
<div id="postdiv"><h3>You entered following data!</h3></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

and below is my process.php

```
         <?php  

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {  


$fullname = $_POST['fname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];   


$to = "davidmasihxyz@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Query For Order Form";
$message = "Your Name:  $fname \n".
           "Your Email:  $email \n" .
           "Your Phone No:  $phone \n" ;


mail($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $email);


echo "Form Submited Successfully..!";

}
else{
    echo "Message Failed..!";
}


?>
```

Please help Jquery is fine and resolve but not able to send mail i guess something is wrong with if (isset($_POST['submit']{.........}

Comment: Typo: `name` instead of `fname` in the object you give the AJAX request. Also note that you could use `$('.form-horizontal').serialize()` instead of building the data manually.

Comment: You can't put someone else's email in the `From` field of an email. It has to be from an email address on the local server.

Comment: Thanks Rory McCrossan &  – 4castle for extra Tips sure i will follow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding. your page is got submitted as submit button post all values. You just need to add return false as per given blow. Your code should work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#submit").click(function(){   


    var  postname = $("#fname").val();

    var postemail = $("#email").val();

    var postphone = $("#phone").val();



      $.post("process.php", {fname:postname, email:postemail, phone:postphone }, function(postresult) {

      $("#postdiv").html(postresult);

    });
return false;

}); 


});
```

Comment: `return false` isn't needed, because there is no `action` attribute on the form for it to submit.

Comment: {fname:postname, email:postemail, phone:postphone, submit:true}   4castle your right its working .

Comment: Thanks Manish Shukla your comments too helped me , again $("#postdiv").html(postresult); was not showing up after adding now my app is great thank you every one for your time and action ....Cheers Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

The object you pass to `$.post` has all the key/value pairs which are sent in the request.

You put

```
{name:postname, email:postemail, phone:postphone }
```

Instead of

```
{fname:postname, email:postemail, phone:postphone }
```

There was a typo on `fname`.

---

To fix the issue with `if (isset($_POST['submit']))`, make sure to include `submit` in your request:

```
{fname:postname, email:postemail, phone:postphone, submit:true}
```

Comment: Thanks  Rory McCrossa i resolved it stackoverflow is great

Comment: but i have seen in some video tuts that we can name it anything and it should match jquery variable name. so they are wrong.

Comment: It doesn't use the variable name (unless you're using the [ES6 object shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)), but you don't have any variables with those names anyway.

Comment: One last thing what if i have to add form in database and send mail() i have to use method POST and jquery does'nt need it but php how to resolve it ?

Comment: i am getting Message Failed